# ocaml toplevel module loading

Tags: load, ocaml

I'm trying to load my modules in .cmo into the toplevel, I had tried:

```
$ ocaml mymodule.cmo
```

I got the toplevel prompt, but I couldn't refer to Mymodule

I also tried the

```
#load "mymodule.cmo"
```

It did not complain but still can't refer to Mymodule

I also tried

```
#use "mymodule.ml"
```

This seems to work, but it does not load the code into the Mymodule namespace, which is a problem because I actually want to load a few modules into top-level, and they refer to each other by their module namespace.

Comment: Ah, I figured out the cause of my problem is the cmo files are in subdirectories, -- ocaml lib/mymodule.cmo. I had to use -- ocaml -I lib mymodule.cmo to be able to refer to it.

Comment: It's great you got things working.  You said when you did `#load "mymodule.cmo"` there was no complaint.  But the toplevel *will* complain if it can't find the module you specify.  Maybe a few things were going wrong at different points.   Regards,

Answer (score 19, accepted):

After you do

```
#load "mymodule.cmo"
```

you can refer to your module, but you still need to use the module name:

```
Mymodule.x
```

If you want to use a simple name (`x`), you also need to `open` the module:

```
open Mymodule
```

This could be the source of your problem.

Here's a session that shows what I'm talking about:

```
$ cat mymodule.ml
let x = 14
$ ocaml312
        Objective Caml version 3.12.0
# load "mymodule.cmo";;
# x;;
Characters 0-1:
  x
  ^
Error: Unbound value x
# Mymodule.x;;
- : int = 14
# open Mymodule;;
# x;;
- : int = 14
#
```